# Plano convex lens refraction angles formula

Tags: optics, refraction, lenses

I am designing an optical device with several plano-convex lenses. In order to determine several measurements I need to be able to calculate the resulting refracted angles at the edges of the lens in a diagram like this: (determine a2 if i know a1)

[image: lens diagram]

However, with no formal education in optics, I'm having a hard time finding an applicable formula for this endeavour. Any help would be appreciated a ton!